# getting text to wrap around flash player / onject

Tags: php, css, html, css-float, soundcloud

i use a bit of code to insert a small soundcloud player inside a wrapper div

my problem is i cant seem to get the object/player to float left so text will wrap around it.. as u can see ive tried adding a class to it but this doesnt seem to work.. can some1 help ?

in my php file i got

```
    } elseif (!empty($track)){
     echo "<object class='track' height='18' width='250'> <param name='movie' value='http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=" . $track . "&amp;show_comments=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=tiny&amp;color=ff7700'></param> <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param> <embed allowscriptaccess='always' height='18' src='http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=" . $track . "&amp;show_comments=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=tiny&amp;color=ff7700' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='250'></embed> </object>";
}
```

and in my css file i got

```
    .track {float: left; margin-right: 5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're floating the object. Try floating the wrapper `div` instead?

Comment: tried that but some reason doesnt change anything.. the first part if the if statement checks if their is an image attached.. if their is it inserts the image instead of the player.. the image floats fine.. just this damn object

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the wrapper div (not the object itself) and give it a width.

Markup:

```
<div class="track-wrapper">
  <object class="track" width="250" ... />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.track-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can give some example CSS that shows how to do that?